# How to include the extension on class

Tags: .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

i am trying to migrate from .NET 4.5 (old) to .NET Core 3.1. (new)

in old one i have a class MvcExtensionMethods that use System.web.Mvc namespace.

```
 namespace System.Web.Mvc
{
    public static class MvcExtensionMethods
    {
       
       
        public static MvcForm BeginEditForm(this AjaxHelper helper, string formId = "addform")
        {
            var queryString = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString;
```

my cshtml file:

```
    @model QualityGateWeb.Models.CriteriaRefViewModel

@{
    var ctxModel = "Criteria Referential";
    ViewBag.Title = Model.Id == 0 ? "New " + ctxModel : ctxModel + " - " + Model.Code;

    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<script>
    @{
        var modelId = @Model.Id;
    }
</script>

@using (Html.BeginEditForm("addform", true))
{
```

in my frontend cshtml, i can use this class as extension like this:
[image]

as you can see on image there is (extension) when i move the mouse over the methode BeginEditForm.

and when i hover the Html is [image]

in .NET 4.5 there is no System.web anymore so i use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering instead

```
using System.Text.Json;

namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering
{
    public static class MvcExtensionMethods
    {
        private static LinkGenerator _linkGenerator;
        private static HttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
        private static HttpContext _HttpContext;

 

        /// <summary>
        /// Create a Form that preserv URL parameter
        /// </summary>
        public static MvcForm BeginEditForm(this HtmlHelper helper, string formId = "addform")
        {
```

but it can not found my methode BeginEditForm.
any idea ?

[image]

Comment: Please add code and data as text (using code formatting), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; C) are difficult to read clearly by visual impaired user and many more reasons. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 0):

Your extension is for a HtmlHelper class, but the Html object in razor is an IHtmlHelper interface. Just change the your extension to be an extension of the interface.